# Preload Collection View (So that scrolling is smooth)

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, collectionview, preloading

I would like to be able to **preload** the items in my collection view when it is being scrolled up and down.

I am using the data of two arrays to load the data in the collection view:

(1) `availableLabelNames: [String]`
(2) `availableImageNames: [String]`

Collection View functions in AvailableImages:

```
class availableImages: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource
{

@IBOutlet weak var searchBar: UISearchBar!

@IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!

public func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int
{
    return availableLabelNames.count
}

public func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell
{
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "customCell", for: indexPath) as! CustomCollectionViewCell
    cell.borderFolder.layer.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
    cell.borderFolder.layer.borderWidth = 2
    cell.borderFolder.layer.cornerRadius = 5

    cell.squareDesign.layer.cornerRadius = 5

    let tapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(availableImages.connected(_:)))
    cell.imageCell.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    cell.imageCell.tag = indexPath.row
    cell.imageCell.addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureRecognizer)

    //setting image
    cell.imageCell.image = UIImage(named: availableImageNames[indexPath.row])

    //setting label
    cell.labelName.text = availableLabelNames[indexPath.row]

    return cell
}
}
```

Custom collection view class:

```
import UIKit

protocol Normal: class
{
    func delete (cell: CustomCollectionViewCell)

    func pressed (cell: CustomCollectionViewCell)

    func textChanged (cell: CustomCollectionViewCell)

    func finishedEditing (cell: CustomCollectionViewCell)

    func textStartedEditing (cell: CustomCollectionViewCell)
}

class CustomCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell
{
    @IBOutlet weak var imageCell: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var deleteButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var cellButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var labelName: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var textFieldName: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var squareDesign: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var borderFolder: UIView!

    weak var delegate: Normal?

    //...class goes on but not important
```

Please could someone help me I have looked everywhere but nothing seems to work or makes sense in terms of my application.
Thank you so much! :)

Answer (score 0):

Collection view is doing preloading by default. Your problem is elsewhere, you can't do heavy work in cell for item.

Would need a sample project to try it on, but I would bet this is the root of the problem:

`cell.imageCell.image = UIImage(named: availableImageNames[indexPath.row])`

rewrite it to this:

```
DispatchQueue.main.async { [weak self] in
    guard let weakSelf = self else { return }
    cell.imageCell.image = UIImage(named: weakSelf.availableImageNames[indexPath.row])
}
```

Also, as cells are reused, you want to reset their image. Otherwise, images will be shown randomly.

Comment: Thank you - I have implemented this. However, I'm not completely sure but it seems to have made it more slow. What did you mean by wanting to 'reset their image' as cells are reused - how can I implement this. Finally, is there any way I could preload this collection view from another view controller. Thanks again!

Comment: Set image to nil beforehand. No, you can't preload collection view from other view controller. Problem is probably you having big images, my code will remove stutter of scrolling, but it will not shorten the time necessary to load your image. If you insist on preloading, you can create cells beforehand, but I don't consider it a good practice as of possible memory problems. A better practice is to make images for cells smaller. Again, that may and not may be a problem as we don't see your full code.